# Are my Cypher statements 'overdone'

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I am using py2neo with transactions. This means I am using the Cypher language. I am *append*ing the textual Cypher statements to a transaction queue and submitting the contents of the queue in one shot with commit.

It works fine. However, it is slow. I am getting about 100/nodes per second and as the transaction queue gets larger the inserts take longer. My app times out if a transaction has more than about 6,000 nodes (and a like amount of relationships).

For now I want to focus on my Cypher. My app generates a lot of this:

```
CREATE (n:METHOD {version: 6995, unique: 682, return_type: 0, fully_qualified_name: 0, name: "method4", accessibility: 0})
CREATE (n:PARAMETER {version: 6995, unique: 687, fully_qualified_name: 0, param_type: 1, name: "param4", accessibility: 0})
MATCH (a:METHOD), (b:PARAMETER) WHERE a.unique=682 AND a.version=6995 AND b.unique=687 AND b.version=6995 CREATE (a)-[r:INVOKED_WITH]->(b)
```

So I create a METHOD node, create a PARAMETER node, then relate them.  What is bothering me is that I basically create the two nodes, then throw away the fact that I just created them. Then I find them with a lookup so I can connect them.  This irks me.  The previous version did not use transactions; when I created a node, I got an native neo4j ID back and used that when creating relations.  Now I can't do that since the textual statements are being submitted en masse to the neo4j server.

Am I allowed to put RETURN statements in there the way I can do in the neo4j web interface? Is there better Cypher to use?

**EDIT** - I have indexes on the "unique" property of all relevant node types.

I am not using parameters in my Python code because the code is using transactions. Therefore I have to use py2neo's mechanism to talk to neo4j directly. This involves creating the textual commands you see above.

Comment: 100 nodes / second looks very slow, even by doing a MATCH that can look unnecessary but it should works really well. I do like 1200 statements in 50ms approximately, so... Now, do you have an index or constraint on all the properties you match on ? do you use parameters in your python code ? Can you post it ?

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen I updated my question. See the edits at the bottom.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about transactions, I can use python with transactions and make use of parameters. Without parameters the execution plans can't be cached, so ..

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen We're using py2neo. According to what I have read, it does not support transactions directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Py2neo supports transactions and of course you can use parameters in the cypher queries, a simple code I just tested :

```
from py2neo import Graph
import time

graph = Graph("http://neo4j:password@localhost:7474/db/data/");

tx = graph.cypher.begin()
for x in range(0,100):
    tx.append("CREATE (m:Method {id:{id}})", {"id": x})
    tx.append("CREATE (p:Parameter {id:{id}})", {"id": x})
    tx.append("MATCH (m:Method {id:{mid}}), (p:Parameter {id: {pid}}) CREATE (m)-[:RELATES]->(p)", {"mid": x, "pid": x})

mstart = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
tx.commit()
mend = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
diff = mend - mstart
print diff
```

The diff time is around 80ms

**Update, you can also do:**

```
    tx.append("CREATE (m:Method {id:{method_id}}) WITH m
               UNWIND {parameter_ids} as p_id 
               CREATE (p:Parameter {id:p_id})
               CREATE (m)-[:RELATES]->(p)", 
              {"method_id": 1234, "parameter_ids":range(0,100)})
```

Comment: Technically, py2neo doesn't support transactions. That's why you can't use native py2neo objects in them. The good folks at py2neo people were kind enough to expose the Cypher interface to us.

NOW I understand what that parameter attribute is for!

One moment while I change my code...

Comment: Your suggestion makes the code _markedly_ faster. I have not implemented it fully so I don't know the final result... but preliminary results are very pleasing.

Comment: cool, also beware that CREATE will not take care of possibly existing nodes with the same ids, or an existing relationship between your nodes, so maybe you'll want to look at the MERGE clause

Comment: Fortunately, this is a loader. There will be no updates and all nodes have a unique ID.  I have made all the changes now, and now I am at 2200+ nodes (with relations)/sec

Comment: If you just do 2 nodes 1 rel at a time you can save the match and directly link m and p together, or a number of parameters to a method with foreach or unwind.

Comment: You should get to 100k / s

Comment: you can also use `tx.append("CREATE (m:Method {data})", {"data":{"id": x,"prop":"value"}})`

Comment: Technically py2neo does support transactions. Don't forget you can also use `tx.process` to send queued statements to the server for processing. These will also return any values specified in a WHERE clause so you get hold of the Node objects if you need them.

Comment: That should have been RETURN clause, not WHERE clause. I haven't had much sleep.

Comment: @MichaelHunger  When I run your(?) snippet in the update, I get an error "WITH is required between CREATE and UNWIND". I added "WITH m" between them and it seemed to work.

Comment: Btw. Tony if you're interested there is a graph-software-analytics google group :) and this: http://neo4j.com/blog/graph-databases-and-software-metrics-analysis/